# Compare & validate two numbers

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I've these code:

```
<%= html.editorFor(x=>x.SalaryForm) %>
<%= html.editorFor(x=>x.salaryTo)   %>
```

I want to compare and validate for (salaryTo >= salaryFrom).

Best thanks to all supporter.

Comment: Obviously I don't know the context but "more or equal" operator is `>=`.

Comment: ok thanks. I'll fix it on #1 post.

Comment: @MichelAyres give you one more thanks, I've answer your reply in other question. "Can you give me a light?"

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are going to want to look into is IValidatableObject. Simply implement this interface in your ViewModel and implement something like this:

```
public class YourViewModel : IValidatableObject
{
    public decimal SalaryFrom { get; set; }
    public decimal SalaryFrom { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (SalaryTo < SalaryFrom)
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult("Salary To must be greater than Salary From", new string[]{"SalaryTo"});
        }
    }
}
```